# Why are there so few CL repos on Github?

Tags: github, lisp, common-lisp

Do CL projects generally use something else (like Haskell-projects do) or is the community really that small?

https://github.com/languages/Common%20Lisp/most_watched

Comment: Doesn't the "most watched" page always show 10 pages of 20 projects per page? It's definitely so for Tcl. All we know from your link is that there *are* at least 200 repositories.

Comment: Yes, but I found it kind of weird that the most watched repos had so few stars.

Comment: About the stars you should understand that the Lisp comunity is somehow "special" in quite a few aspects. For example you will not get thanks for pointing out minor errors in CLHS, but insults.

Comment: @6502: sounds like FUD. http://www.cliki.net/Proposed%20ANSI%20Revisions%20and%20Clarifications

Comment: @RainerJoswig: I was in #lisp and reported that in CLHS code for nconc in the example section mutates IIUC a quoted list (a bad thing). I was not pointed to that page (that by the way now I see that already lists the bug I found independently)... I was simply mistreated for no reasons at all by a couple of "regulars".

Comment: @6502: #lisp is not 'the Lisp community'. It was only one guy who was confused and others later explained it to him. The Hyperspec is only a derivation of the ANSI CL standard document (it has no semantic changes). The ANSI CL standard has several places, where such problematic examples are presented. As you see on the CLiki pages I've given you, the people in the 'Common Lisp' community who care about the standard are aware of these problems.

Answer (score 5):

A project to provide access to Common Lisp libraries is [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org). See the [list of libraries](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/releases.html).

For hosted projects see also: [common-lisp.net](http://common-lisp.net) . Also sourceforge and others...